# Windows Azure VM cannot access microsoft.com

Tags: dns, azure-vm-role

I have 2 VM's on Windows Azure, connected with a virtual network, including the "DNS" component linked to the virtual network.

The first machine is an AD controller (with DNS), and the DNS from the virtual network (in Azure) is pointed to this machine (10.0.0.4).

The 2 vm's can talk to each other, and the second VM is also domain joined with the AD controller on the first machine.

The problem is, on both VM's, I cannot access/browse to anything related to microsoft.com (like visualstudio.com, etc). All other sites (even bing.com) work without any problem.

What could be the reason. Do I need to change some DNS settings on my first VM so that microsoft.com is "excluded" or something. As I suppose that this is "internal" microsoft traffic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved! You need to add the Google DNS to the list of DNS servers in the management portal, and link it to your Virtual Network.

To do so, add one or both of Google's DNS IP addresses (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) to the list of DNS servers associated with an Azure virtual network. In the Azure management portal, go to 'Virtual Networks > [Your virtual network] > DNS Servers', then add the addresses to the list and click Save.